# Arraylist in arraylist sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, arraylist, bubble-sort

I have an arraylist. it keeps arraylists in it. For example;

```
 ar1 -> {2,3,46,67}  keeps 4 members. 
 ar2 -> {28,96,67} keeps 3 members.
 ar2 -> {56,32,67,54,214} keeps 5 members. 
 Ar_main[0]= ar1 
 Ar_main[1]= ar2 
 Ar_main[2]= ar3
```

i want to sort ar_main order by count of members. i used bubble sort algorithm. but it didn't work, can't we sort arraylist like this method?

```
private void sortArrayToAscending(ArrayList ar)
    {
        ArrayList ar1,ar2;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.Count - 1; i++) 
         for (int j = 1; j < ar.Count - i; j++)
          {
             ar1 = (ArrayList)ar[j];
             ar2 = (ArrayList)ar[j-1];
             if (ar1.Count < ar2.Count)
             {
                 ArrayList temp = ar2;
                 ar2=ar1;
                 ar1=temp;             
             }           
          }
    }
```

Comment: You are not putting ar1/ar2 back in ar. ar1 and ar2 are just local references. ar is not actually modified. You need to put them in correct locations in ar.

Comment: First, stop using `ArrayList`. No program written in .Net since November 2005 should use it. Use `List<T>` instead. Once you've done that, you can use LINQ to make this really easy: `var sortedList = list.OrderBy(subList => subList.Count);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in [`Sort` method in the `ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0e743hdt) that does the sorting for you. What you have to provide is an [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.icomparer) implementation that *compares the list*, making their length the criteria:

```
public void ArrayListSort()
{
    var list = new ArrayList();
    list.Sort(new LengthComparer());
}

class LengthComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var a = x as ArrayList;
        var b = y as ArrayList;
        // check for null if you need to!
        return a.Count.CompareTo(b.Count);
    }
}
```

However, unless you're actually using .NET 1.1, I'd recommend that you use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `ArrayList`, and the LINQ [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This is type-safe, and I'd consider it more idiomatic C# nowadays. On top of that, it's way shorter:

```
var typedList = new List<List<int>>();
var sortedList = typedList.OrderBy(i => i.Count).ToList();
```

Be aware that the former is an *in-place sort* (altering the original list), whereas the latter copies the result into a new list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to comment yet or else I would. C# contains a built in static method in the ArrayList class. It sorts using the QuickSort algorithm. You may want to give it a try and see if it helps.
[Microsoft API Documentation ArrayList.Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)